# Update Location Marker and draw path on Google Maps V2 while walking/driving in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I wanted to draw the path on Google Maps V2 when driving or walking, I couldn't find any online resource to help me with this problem.
I'm using the onLocationChanged listener method.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extend OnMyLocationChangeListener.

use this in the map-setup:

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
```

override this:

```
@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
          /* your code here */
}
```

for example the code could be something like this (NOT TESTED):

```
    Location lastLocationloc=null;
@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    if(lastLocationloc == null)
        lastLocationloc = location;
    LatLng lastLatLng= locationToLatLng(lastLocationloc);
    LatLng thisLatLng= locationToLatLng(location);
    mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(lastLatLng).add(thisLatLng).width(3).color(Color.RED));
    lastLocationloc = location;
}
```

the locationToLatLng could look something like this:

```
public static LatLng locationToLatLng(Location loc) {
    if(loc != null)
        return new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As been said here you need to use the `Polyline` object, you can collect all your path points (`LatLng` locations) and add all the road on the map using a loop:

```
Polyline newPolyline;
GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); 
PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);

for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoints.size() ; i++) 
{          
    rectLine.add(directionPoints.get(i));
}
newPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
```

Or add a single line on each location update so place this code in the `onLocationChanged`

```
Polyline newPolyline;
PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);
rectLine.add(point); //your received location.
newPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
```

To update the marker's location, just remove the old one and create a new marker (with the new coordinates) instead.

Comment: Hi Emil Adz,Thanks for the answer, but i need to draw the line while walking/driving, the line should draw live when im moving.... im using onLocationChanged method is there any way this can match my scenario.

Comment: as I said in the second part: "add a single line on each location update", so place the second snippet into the onLocationChanged  method

Comment: @Emil I have a similar problem except mine is animating a marker from live stream of location objects instead of drawing a polyline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Polyline from Google Maps. It takes locations and draws them on the map.